# Matching Regex Patterns with symbols

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm looking to match a regex pattern. I know that my code will not work if there's any symbol character (except for _ ) at the start of the word. How do I allow it to match words that start with any symbol?
Here's my code so far:

---

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With objRegex
 .Pattern = "(\nC_PIN\s)((\b[^\s]+\b\s){3})(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b\d\b\s)"
 .Global = True
Set objFil = objFso.OpenTextFile(infilename)
 strAll = objFil.ReadAll
 Set objFil1 = objFso.createtextfile(outfilename)
 strAll = .Replace(strAll, "$1$2$4 $5 $6 ")
End With

objFil.Close
objFil2.Close
```

---

Comment: try `\W` (matches a NON word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

Comment: If you're okay with leading spaces too, then the expression `^\s*\w` matches a line that begins with a word character (as pointed out by @sgroves), ignoring leading spaces.

Comment: [^\s] should be replaced by \S.

Comment: The grouping in the pattern is `(group1)(group2(group3,4,5){3})(group6)(group7)(group8)` and group2 includes group3 up to group5. So maybe your intended replace part is `"$1$2$6 $7 $8"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get the right code. The code used to match a word beginning with a symbol is  (or a negative number);

> Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>
> Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
>
> With objRegex
>
> .Pattern = "(\nC_PIN\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)([\S]+\b\s)([\S]+\b\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b\d\b\s)"
>
> .Global = True
>       Set objFil = objFso.OpenTextFile(infilename)
>
> ```
> strAll = objFil.ReadAll
>
> Set objFil1 = objFso.createtextfile(outfilename)
>
> strAll = .Replace(strAll, "$1$2$4 $5 $6 ")
> End With
> ```
>
> objFil.Close
>
> objFil2.Close

Comment: [\S] should be simplified to \S. And nevertheless this is not the answer to your original question.

Comment: @leonardo12, this code does exactly what I was asking for. I have used it on test files as well as the proper files I needed it to work on. Every line now has matched the correct pattern, regardless of any symbols (which is exactly the question asked). I left in the square brackets by mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`\b[^\s]+\b` does not make sense, cause [\b is an anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) searching for begin or end of a word. And word is always [a-zA-Z0-9_].

I think you can only use something like:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9_!"§$%&...][a-zA-Z0-9_!"§$%&...]`

where you should insert all symbol characters you allow for a word (in your interpretation).

Comment: It seems that the minus symbol is used to describe a range of characters. Is there a way to use it to include minus numbers?

Comment: I managed to get the right code. The pattern used to match a word beginning with a symbol is, `([\S]+\b\s)`. This also works for negative numbers!

Comment: A minus character is processed as literal character if it is the last one (or the first after the ^) within the brackets: [a-zA-Z0-9_-], [-a-zA-Z0-9_]. Btw: backslash escaping is not allowed within brackets.